# Mass edit a Campaign Member Blocktable

Tags: apex, pageblocktable, campaign-member, mass-action

My team is using campaigns extensively for a handful of different recordtypes and a lot of time is wasted by having to click into each campaign members records to update information.

I set out as an apex newbie to build a custom class extension and blocktable. I have the table so in-line editing works, and placed optional filters at the top, but I cannot figure out how to get a column of checkboxes to work for mass-editing fields the same way a normal list-view works. Can anyone help? My code is below.

```
public with sharing class CampaignRelatedListExtension
{
    public CampaignMember campmemb { get; set; }
    public Campaign camp{get; set;}
    public List<CampaignMember> campaignMembers{ get; set;}
    
    public List<Campaign> listCampaign{ 
        get{
            return[select Id, Name from Campaign];
        }
    }


    public Boolean C1{ get; set; }
    public Boolean C2{ get; set; }
    public Boolean C3{ get; set; }
    public Boolean C4{ get; set; }
    public Boolean C5{ get; set; }
    public Boolean C6{ get; set; }
    
   
    public void incampaignMembers(){
        if(C1 == FALSE && C2 == FALSE && C3 == FALSE && C4 == FALSE && C5 == FALSE && C6 == FALSE ){
                    campaignMembers = [select Id, Name, Political_Philosophy__c, Status, FirstName, LastName, Email, DOB__c, State, Referral_Rev_2021__c, School_Alma_Mater__c, User__c, Region__c, Phone
                                       from CampaignMember
                                       where CampaignId = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id') 
                                       LIMIT 1000] ;                    
        }
        else if (C1 == TRUE && C2 == FALSE && C3 == FALSE && C4 == FALSE && C5 == FALSE && C6 == FALSE ){
                    campaignMembers = [select Id, Name, Political_Philosophy__c, Status, FirstName, LastName, Email, DOB__c, State, Referral_Rev_2021__c, School_Alma_Mater__c, User__c, Region__c, Phone
                                       from CampaignMember
                                       where CampaignId = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id') 
                                       and Status = :campmemb.Status 
                                       LIMIT 1000] ;                    
        }        
        else if (C1 == FALSE && C2 == TRUE && C3 == FALSE && C4 == FALSE && C5 == FALSE && C6 == FALSE ){
                    campaignMembers = [select Id, Name, Political_Philosophy__c, Status, FirstName, LastName, Email, DOB__c, State, Referral_Rev_2021__c, School_Alma_Mater__c, User__c, Region__c, Phone
                                       from CampaignMember
                                       where CampaignId = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')  
                                       and Region__c = :campmemb.Region__c 
                                       LIMIT 1000] ;                    
        }        
        else if (C1 == FALSE && C2 == FALSE && C3 == TRUE && C4 == FALSE && C5 == FALSE && C6 == FALSE ){
                    campaignMembers = [select Id, Name, Political_Philosophy__c, Status, FirstName, LastName, Email, DOB__c, State, Referral_Rev_2021__c, School_Alma_Mater__c, User__c, Region__c, Phone
                                       from CampaignMember
                                       where CampaignId = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')  
                                       and State = :campmemb.State 
                                       LIMIT 1000] ;                    
        }        
        else if (C1 == FALSE && C2 == FALSE && C3 == FALSE && C4 == TRUE && C5 == FALSE && C6 == FALSE ){
                    campaignMembers = [select Id, Name, Political_Philosophy__c, Status, FirstName, LastName, Email, DOB__c, State, Referral_Rev_2021__c, School_Alma_Mater__c, User__c, Region__c, Phone
                                       from CampaignMember
                                       where CampaignId = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')  
                                       and School_Alma_Mater__c = :campmemb.School_Alma_Mater__c 
                                       LIMIT 1000] ;                    
        }        
        else if (C1 == FALSE && C2 == FALSE && C3 == FALSE && C4 == FALSE && C5 == TRUE && C6 == FALSE ){
                    campaignMembers = [select Id, Name, Political_Philosophy__c, Status, FirstName, LastName, Email, DOB__c, State, Referral_Rev_2021__c, School_Alma_Mater__c, User__c, Region__c, Phone
                                       from CampaignMember
                                       where CampaignId = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')  
                                       and Referral_Rev_2021__c = :campmemb.Referral_Rev_2021__c 
                                       LIMIT 1000] ;                    
        }        
        else if (C1 == FALSE && C2 == FALSE && C3 == FALSE && C4 == FALSE && C5 == FALSE && C6 == TRUE ){
                    campaignMembers = [select Id, Name, Political_Philosophy__c, Status, FirstName, LastName, Email, DOB__c, State, Referral_Rev_2021__c, School_Alma_Mater__c, User__c, Region__c, Phone
                                       from CampaignMember
                                       where CampaignId = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')  
                                       and User__c = :campmemb.User__c 
                                       LIMIT 1000] ;                    
        }        
        else if (C1 == TRUE && C2 == TRUE && C3 == FALSE && C4 == FALSE && C5 == FALSE && C6 == FALSE ){
                    campaignMembers = [select Id, Name, Political_Philosophy__c, Status, FirstName, LastName, Email, DOB__c, State, Referral_Rev_2021__c, School_Alma_Mater__c, User__c, Region__c, Phone
                                       from CampaignMember
                                       where CampaignId = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id') 
                                       and Status = :campmemb.Status  
                                       and Region__c = :campmemb.Region__c 
                                       LIMIT 1000] ;                    
        }        
        else if (C1 == TRUE && C2 == FALSE && C3 == TRUE && C4 == FALSE && C5 == FALSE && C6 == FALSE ){
                    campaignMembers = [select Id, Name, Political_Philosophy__c, Status, FirstName, LastName, Email, DOB__c, State, Referral_Rev_2021__c, School_Alma_Mater__c, User__c, Region__c, Phone
                                       from CampaignMember
                                       where CampaignId = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')  
                                       and State = :campmemb.State 
                                       and Status = :campmemb.Status 
                                       LIMIT 1000] ;                    
        }        
        else if (C1 == TRUE && C2 == FALSE && C3 == FALSE && C4 == TRUE && C5 == FALSE && C6 == FALSE ){
                    campaignMembers = [select Id, Name, Political_Philosophy__c, Status, FirstName, LastName, Email, DOB__c, State, Referral_Rev_2021__c, School_Alma_Mater__c, User__c, Region__c, Phone
                                       from CampaignMember
                                       where CampaignId = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')  
                                       and School_Alma_Mater__c = :campmemb.School_Alma_Mater__c 
                                       and Status = :campmemb.Status 
                                       LIMIT 1000] ;                    
        }        
        else if (C1 == TRUE && C2 == FALSE && C3 == FALSE && C4 == FALSE && C5 == TRUE && C6 == FALSE ){
                    campaignMembers = [select Id, Name, Political_Philosophy__c, Status, FirstName, LastName, Email, DOB__c, State, Referral_Rev_2021__c, School_Alma_Mater__c, User__c, Region__c, Phone
                                       from CampaignMember
                                       where CampaignId = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')  
                                       and Referral_Rev_2021__c = :campmemb.Referral_Rev_2021__c 
                                       and Status = :campmemb.Status 
                                       LIMIT 1000] ;                    
        }        
        else if (C1 == TRUE && C2 == FALSE && C3 == FALSE && C4 == FALSE && C5 == FALSE && C6 == TRUE ){
                    campaignMembers = [select Id, Name, Political_Philosophy__c, Status, FirstName, LastName, Email, DOB__c, State, Referral_Rev_2021__c, School_Alma_Mater__c, User__c, Region__c, Phone
                                       from CampaignMember
                                       where CampaignId = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')  
                                       and User__c = :campmemb.User__c 
                                       and Status = :campmemb.Status 
                                       LIMIT 1000] ;                    
        }        
        else if (C1 == FALSE && C2 == TRUE && C3 == TRUE && C4 == FALSE && C5 == FALSE && C6 == FALSE ){
                    campaignMembers = [select Id, Name, Political_Philosophy__c, Status, FirstName, LastName, Email, DOB__c, State, Referral_Rev_2021__c, School_Alma_Mater__c, User__c, Region__c, Phone
                                       from CampaignMember
                                       where CampaignId = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id') 
                                       and State = :campmemb.State  
                                       and Region__c = :campmemb.Region__c 
                                       LIMIT 1000] ;                    
        }        
        else if (C1 == FALSE && C2 == TRUE && C3 == FALSE && C4 == TRUE && C5 == FALSE && C6 == FALSE ){
                    campaignMembers = [select Id, Name, Political_Philosophy__c, Status, FirstName, LastName, Email, DOB__c, State, Referral_Rev_2021__c, School_Alma_Mater__c, User__c, Region__c, Phone
                                       from CampaignMember
                                       where CampaignId = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')  
                                       and Region__c = :campmemb.Region__c 
                                       and School_Alma_Mater__c = :campmemb.School_Alma_Mater__c 
                                       LIMIT 1000] ;                    
        }        
        else if (C1 == FALSE && C2 == TRUE && C3 == FALSE && C4 == FALSE && C5 == TRUE && C6 == FALSE ){
                    campaignMembers = [select Id, Name, Political_Philosophy__c, Status, FirstName, LastName, Email, DOB__c, State, Referral_Rev_2021__c, School_Alma_Mater__c, User__c, Region__c, Phone
                                       from CampaignMember
                                       where CampaignId = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')  
                                       and Referral_Rev_2021__c = :campmemb.Referral_Rev_2021__c 
                                       and Region__c = :campmemb.Region__c 
                                       LIMIT 1000] ;                    
        }        
        else if (C1 == FALSE && C2 == TRUE && C3 == FALSE && C4 == FALSE && C5 == FALSE && C6 == TRUE ){
                    campaignMembers = [select Id, Name, Political_Philosophy__c, Status, FirstName, LastName, Email, DOB__c, State, Referral_Rev_2021__c, School_Alma_Mater__c, User__c, Region__c, Phone
                                       from CampaignMember
                                       where CampaignId = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')  
                                       and User__c = :campmemb.User__c 
                                       and Region__c = :campmemb.Region__c 
                                       LIMIT 1000] ;                    
        }        
        else if (C1 == FALSE && C2 == FALSE && C3 == TRUE && C4 == TRUE && C5 == FALSE && C6 == FALSE ){
                    campaignMembers = [select Id, Name, Political_Philosophy__c, Status, FirstName, LastName, Email, DOB__c, State, Referral_Rev_2021__c, School_Alma_Mater__c, User__c, Region__c, Phone
                                       from CampaignMember
                                       where CampaignId = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id') 
                                       and State = :campmemb.State  
                                       and School_Alma_Mater__c = :campmemb.School_Alma_Mater__c 
                                       LIMIT 1000] ;                    
        }        
        else if (C1 == FALSE && C2 == FALSE && C3 == TRUE && C4 == FALSE && C5 == TRUE && C6 == FALSE ){
                    campaignMembers = [select Id, Name, Political_Philosophy__c, Status, FirstName, LastName, Email, DOB__c, State, Referral_Rev_2021__c, School_Alma_Mater__c, User__c, Region__c, Phone
                                       from CampaignMember
                                       where CampaignId = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')  
                                       and State = :campmemb.State 
                                       and Referral_Rev_2021__c = :campmemb.Referral_Rev_2021__c 
                                       LIMIT 1000] ;                    
        }        
        else if (C1 == FALSE && C2 == FALSE && C3 == TRUE && C4 == FALSE && C5 == FALSE && C6 == TRUE ){
                    campaignMembers = [select Id, Name, Political_Philosophy__c, Status, FirstName, LastName, Email, DOB__c, State, Referral_Rev_2021__c, School_Alma_Mater__c, User__c, Region__c, Phone
                                       from CampaignMember
                                       where CampaignId = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')  
                                       and State = :campmemb.State 
                                       and User__c = :campmemb.User__c 
                                       LIMIT 1000] ;                    
        }        
        else if (C1 == FALSE && C2 == FALSE && C3 == FALSE && C4 == TRUE && C5 == TRUE && C6 == FALSE ){
                    campaignMembers = [select Id, Name, Political_Philosophy__c, Status, FirstName, LastName, Email, DOB__c, State, Referral_Rev_2021__c, School_Alma_Mater__c, User__c, Region__c, Phone
                                       from CampaignMember
                                       where CampaignId = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id') 
                                       and School_Alma_Mater__c = :campmemb.School_Alma_Mater__c  
                                       and Referral_Rev_2021__c = :campmemb.Referral_Rev_2021__c 
                                       LIMIT 1000] ;                    
        }        
        else if (C1 == FALSE && C2 == FALSE && C3 == FALSE && C4 == TRUE && C5 == FALSE && C6 == TRUE ){
                    campaignMembers = [select Id, Name, Political_Philosophy__c, Status, FirstName, LastName, Email, DOB__c, State, Referral_Rev_2021__c, School_Alma_Mater__c, User__c, Region__c, Phone
                                       from CampaignMember
                                       where CampaignId = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')  
                                       and School_Alma_Mater__c = :campmemb.School_Alma_Mater__c  
                                       and User__c = :campmemb.User__c 
                                       LIMIT 1000] ;                    
        }        
        else if (C1 == FALSE && C2 == FALSE && C3 == FALSE && C4 == FALSE && C5 == TRUE && C6 == TRUE ){
                    campaignMembers = [select Id, Name, Political_Philosophy__c, Status, FirstName, LastName, Email, DOB__c, State, Referral_Rev_2021__c, School_Alma_Mater__c, User__c, Region__c, Phone
                                       from CampaignMember
                                       where CampaignId = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')  
                                       and Referral_Rev_2021__c = :campmemb.Referral_Rev_2021__c  
                                       and User__c = :campmemb.User__c 
                                       LIMIT 1000] ;                    
        }        
        else {
                 campaignMembers = [select Id, Name, Political_Philosophy__c, Status, FirstName, LastName, Email, DOB__c, State, Referral_Rev_2021__c, School_Alma_Mater__c, User__c, Region__c, Phone
                    from CampaignMember 
                    where CampaignId = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id') 
                    LIMIT 1000 ] ;   
        }        

    }    

    
    
    public CampaignRelatedListExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
            campmemb = new CampaignMember(Political_Philosophy__c = NULL, Status = 'Applied' , Region__c = 'Midwest');
            camp = new Campaign();
            incampaignMembers();
    }
    
    public PageReference savecampmemb() {
    update campaignMembers;
    return null;
    }
    
    public void initPage() {
        
    }
    
}
```

---

```
<apex:page lightningStylesheets="true" action="{!initPage}" standardController="Campaign" extensions="CampaignRelatedListExtension" >
    <apex:pageMessages />
 
          

            <apex:form >
                <apex:pageBlock title="Filter Results - Only select two max" >
                    <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom" >
                        <apex:commandButton value="Go" action="{!incampaignMembers}" reRender="dataTable" />
                    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
                    
                <apex:panelGrid columns="3" >
                    <apex:inputCheckbox id="checkboxShowP1" value="{!C1}" onchange="show(this);" />
                    <apex:outputText value="Status"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!campmemb.Status}" />

                    <apex:inputCheckbox id="checkboxShowP2" value="{!C2}" onchange="show(this);" />
                    <apex:outputText value="Region"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!campmemb.Region__c}" />

                    <apex:inputCheckbox id="checkboxShowP3" value="{!C3}" onchange="show(this);" />
                    <apex:outputText value="State"/>
                    <apex:inputText value="{!campmemb.State}" />
                    
                    <apex:inputCheckbox id="checkboxShowP4" value="{!C4}" onchange="show(this);" />
                    <apex:outputText value="School"/>
                    <apex:inputText value="{!campmemb.School_Alma_Mater__c}" />

                    <apex:inputCheckbox id="checkboxShowP5" value="{!C5}" onchange="show(this);" />
                    <apex:outputText value="Referral"/>
                    <apex:inputText value="{!campmemb.Referral_Rev_2021__c}" />

                    <apex:inputCheckbox id="checkboxShowP6" value="{!C6}" onchange="show(this);" />
                    <apex:outputText value="User"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!campmemb.User__c}" />


                </apex:panelGrid>
                </apex:pageBlock>
            </apex:form>            


            <apex:form >           
                <apex:pageBlock title="Campaign Members" >
                    <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top" >
                        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!savecampmemb}" />
                    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
                    <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom" >
                        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!savecampmemb}" />
                    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
                    
                    <apex:pageBlockTable id="dataTable" value="{!campaignMembers}" var="member">
                        <apex:column ><apex:inputCheckbox /></apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Member Name"> <apex:outputLink value="/{!member.Id}">{!member.Name}</apex:outputLink></apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Status"><apex:selectList value="{!member.Status}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Applied" itemLabel="Applied"/>
                            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Attended" itemLabel="Attended"/>
                            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Checked In" itemLabel="Checked In"/>
                            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Complete" itemLabel="Complete"/>
                            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Confirm" itemLabel="Confirm"/>
                            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Declined" itemLabel="Declined"/>
                            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Flake" itemLabel="Flake"/>
                            <apex:selectOption itemValue="HODL" itemLabel="HODL"/>
                            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Lock" itemLabel="Lock"/>
                            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Minor Offered" itemLabel="Minor Offered"/>
                            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Minor Recommended" itemLabel="Minor Recommended"/>
                            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Needs New Birthdate" itemLabel="Needs New Birthdate"/>
                            <apex:selectOption itemValue="No Outreach Attempted" itemLabel="No Outreach Attempted"/>
                            <apex:selectOption itemValue="No Show" itemLabel="No Show"/>
                            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Offered" itemLabel="Offered"/>
                            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Recommended" itemLabel="Recommended"/>
                            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Registered" itemLabel="Registered"/>
                            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Rejected" itemLabel="Rejected"/>
                            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Responded" itemLabel="Responded"/>
                            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Revoked" itemLabel="Revoked"/>
                            </apex:selectList></apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Region"><apex:inputField value="{!member.Region__c}" /></apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Email"><apex:outputText value="{!member.Email}" /></apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Phone"><apex:outputText value="{!member.Phone}" /></apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="DOB"><apex:outputText value="{0,date,dd'/'MM'/'yyyy}" ><apex:param value="{!member.DOB__c}" /></apex:outputText></apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="School / Alma Mater"><apex:outputField value="{!member.School_Alma_Mater__c}" /></apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="State"><apex:outputField value="{!member.State}" /></apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Referral"><apex:outputField value="{!member.Referral_Rev_2021__c}" /></apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="User"><apex:inputField value="{!member.User__c}" /></apex:column>
                        <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblClick" showOnEdit="saveButton,cancelButton" hideOnEdit="editButton" /> 
                    </apex:pageBlockTable>
                </apex:pageBlock>
            </apex:form>                

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have most of what you need, you just apparently need a way to map the checkbox to some Apex code. This means you need a wrapper class. Here's my standard go-to example:

```
CampaignMember[] campaignMembers;
Set<Id> selectedRecordIds = new Set<Id>();
// This goes in your already existing class
public class Wrapper {
    public CampaignMember member { get; set; }
    Set<Id> recordIds;
    public Wrapper(Set<Id> selectedRecordIds, CampaignMember record) {
        this.recordIds = selectedRecordIds;
        member = record;
    }
    public Boolean getIsSelected() {
        return recordIds.contains(member.Id);
    }
    public void setIsSelected(Boolean value) {
        if(value) {
            this.recordIds.add(member.Id);
        } else {
            this.recordIds.remove(member.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you just wrap up your items:

```
public Wrapper[] getWrappers() {
    Wrapper[] results = new Wrapper[0];
    for(CampaignMember record: campaignMembers) {
        results.add(new Wrapper(selectedRecordIds, record));
    }
    return results;
}
```

Then, in your Visualforce page, you just need to wire everything up to the new attributes:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable id="dataTable" value="{!wrappers}" var="record">
    <apex:column ><apex:inputCheckbox value="{!record.isSelected}" /></apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Member Name"> <apex:outputLink value="/{!record.member.Id}">{!record.member.Name}</apex:outputLink></apex:column>
    <!-- every other `{!member.X}` becomes `{!record.member.X}` -->
    <!-- examples -->
    <apex:column headerValue="Region"><apex:inputField value="{!record.member.Region__c}" /></apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Email"><apex:outputText value="{!record.member.Email}" /></apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Phone"><apex:outputText value="{!record.member.Phone}" /></apex:column>
```

---

Now, some explanation is in order here.

First, we can't just attach a random variable to an sObject, so we need a wrapper class that holds these "extra" attributes. In this case, there's just one, but it might include calculations and other things. Wrapper classes are immensely useful.

Next, a method called getX() or setX() in a Visualforce page will have the effect of being linked to attributes via `{!x}` for reading or writing, respectively. The list is effectively read-only, but driven from the campaignMembers variable.

After that, we should know that variables are passed by reference. That means when we pass in selectedRecordIds to the Wrapper constructor, the getter/setter methods are all referencing the same object in memory, so a change in the Set will be seen by all the other wrappers as well.

Similarly, when you inline edit a record in the table, it will automatically update the values in the campaignMembers list, even though we didn't directly modify those variables; again, we pass by reference, so we can refer to the object by multiple variables.

We use this to our advantage to avoid having to interrogate a master list of Id values, pulling the values out in a secondary loop, etc. It's all very magical looking, and saves a bit of code.

There are some other optimizations available to you as well. Notably, your main query should only be about 40-50 lines of code, not the 170+ lines of code you have right now, and will also simultaneously support 0-6 filters without writing what would end up being thousands of lines of code.

What you're looking for is [Dynamic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm), which involves using a String to be more productive. Here's a basic 1.0 version:

```
public void incampaignMembers(){
    String campaignId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
    String campaignStatus = campmemb.Status;
    String region = campmemb.Region__c;
    String state = campmemb.State;
    String almaMater = campmemb.School_Alma_Mater__c;
    String referralRev2011 = campmemb.Referral_Rev_2021__c;
    String selectedUser = campmemb.User__c;
    String[] filters = new String[0];
    filters.add('CampaignId = :campaignId');
    if(C1) {
        filters.add('Status = :campaignStatus');
    }
    if(C2) {
        filters.add('Region__c = :region');
    }
    if(C3) {
        filters.add('State = :state');
    }
    if(C4) {
        filters.add('School_Alma_Mater__c = :almaMater');
    }
    if(C5) {
        filters.add('Referral_Rev_2021__c = :referralRev2011');
    }
    if(C6) {
        filters.add('User__c = :selectedUser');
    }
    String query = 'SELECT Name, Political_Philosophy__c, Status, FirstName, LastName, Email, DOB__c, State, Referral_Rev_2021__c, School_Alma_Mater__c, User__c, Region__c, Phone FROM CampaignMember' +
        ' WHERE' + String.join(filters, ' AND ') +
        ' LIMIT 1000';
    campaignMembers = Database.query(query);
}
```

The only downside here is that `object.value` notations are not supported, so we have to spend a few extra lines of code assigning them to separate variables. Aside from that, we end up with a very nice bit of code that supports any combination of filters.

As a side note, don't name your variables C1, C2, etc. That's not very descriptive, and when someone needs to maintain your code later, they won't be thanking you for it (this potentially includes your future self years later). You can have long, descriptive variables up to 40 letters and numbers long. Take advantage of that.

As for mass editing, you just need to create an input somewhere, then use the selectedRecordIds variable to determine which records to modify. You haven't really created a UI for that yet, so I leave that as an exercise to you, but this answer should get you most of the way there.